# Laravel request url with parameter problem with GET Method

Tags: php, laravel, http, url, postman

I have a route in `api.php` which look like this:

```
Route::get('auth/logout/{token}','UserController.php';
```

I tested this API endpoint using Postman with these configurations:

- Method: GET
- Params: `key` = token; `value` = `$2y$10$Xji0VW1Qq9rtF04QlXDu1ePKNKHpRA2ppjDYWNFX.37C30sd3WSIu`
- Header: *none*
- URL: `localhost:8000/api/v1/logout?token=$2y$10$Xji0VW1Qq9rtF04QlXDu1ePKNKHpRA2ppjDYWNFX.37C30sd3WSIu`

Here is my `UserController@logout`:

```
public function logout($token){
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Logout Success',
        'token' => $token
    ], 200);
}
```

As you can see there, I just want to show a message and the `$token` parameter in Postman. But my problem is, Postman shows me a blank response. I can't access the URL with `?` as the parameter separator. But I can access the URL with `/`, just like `host/api/v1/auth/logout/{token_value}`. But it is not what I desired. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `token` route parameter:

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'UserController.php');
```

And retrieve the token from the request in the controller:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Logout Success',
        'token' => $request->token
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Oh, dude!!! Thanks a lot! This is what I searched for. Thanks, @Remul. I am sorry for my edit.

Comment: @DaniFadli You can type-hint the request like it is now, or use the `request('token')` helper function, both work.